# React rendering before array is populated from GET Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, so pointers also welcome.

I am populating an array with the json of an api call:

```
fetch('/rpa').then(rpa => rpa.json()).then(data => data.rpa).then(nestedData=>nestedData.forEach(item => jsonRespnse.push(item)));
console.log(jsonRespnse)
```

Logging to the console shows the data as I would expect. However, putting that data in as part of my return, I am not getting anything:

```
  return (
        <div>
                {rpaName.map((rpaItem, i) => (
                <div>
                <div className='headerContainer' onClick={()=>toggle(i)}>
                <h4 className='rpaHeader'>{rpaItem}</h4><span className='rpaSpan'>{selected === i ? '-': '+'}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={selected === i ? 'rpaButton show': 'rpaButton'}>
                <button onClick={()=>sendData(rpaItem)}>Start{rpaItem}</button><button>Stop{rpaItem}</button>
                </div>
                <br></br>
                </div>))}
        </div>);}
```

I am assuming its a timing thing, with the rendering taking place before the array can be populated, when I hard code an array it works fine.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: A typical approach is to handle rendering before the data is ready, like with a spinner/placeholder/etc.

Comment: Use react state instead of mutating the variable

Comment: you could prevent with [conditional operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) `rpaName && rpaName.map`

Comment: use `jsonResponse` as a way to check your API call resolved with actual data, when that happens you need to make your component render template based on the condition that the `jsonResponse` exists. As mentioned above, you can create a loader / spinner component to render a template when `jsonResponse` does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using functional components, you can use the `useEffect` hook of react to perform the API call before rendering your component.

Then you can use the `useState` hook to declare a state variable to hold the fetched data.

Sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const yourComponent = () => {
   const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetch('<URL>').then(response => response.json()).then(responseArr => setData(responseArr)));
   }, []);

   return(
    //Rest of the code (Now you can use the fetched data as an array since "data" state's been populated with the data fetched from the API call)
   );
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that the useEffect is within a component...

Comment: My bad, hope now it's clearer @ChristianMoen

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make the component rerender within itself is to use `state`.

In React world, since you didn't provide the full component, I'm assuming you're using functional components, in which you have hooks such as useState, and useEffect.

useState is where you'd place your changing variables to.

Example.

```js
function MyComponent() {
   // the first variable here is the actual value of the state, the next is the function to change the state.
   const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(); 

   // when we move over to useEffect, is the hook that'd typically use to perform fetch requests for example. 

   React.useEffect(() => {
       fetch(...).then(response => response.json()).then(setMyState);
   }, [])

   return <div>{myState}</div>
}
```

When the state gets a new value, it will rerender the component to reflect the new change.

Comment: So, from your example I have done: `code`
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(); 

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('/rpa').then(response => response.json()).then(setMyState);
    console.log(jsonRespnse)
  }) But All I am getting 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined' for myState.map ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, you can do optional chaining and check if you have a map function in your state by doing this `myState?.map(....` @JadenWalker

Answer (score 1):

you're probably wanting to set the request array as a state object so something like

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function someReactComponent() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [fetchResponse, setFetchResponse] = useState([]);

  fetch('/yourfetchurl').then(response => response.json()).then(responseArr => setFetchResponse(responseArr)));
  
  return (
    <div>
      {fetchResponse.map((res, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            {res.whatever}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your responses - I managed to get there with a combination of all of them really, so thankyou.

Once I got the useState + useEffect combo in there, it was just a case of how the JSON was being put into the array, this is what was giving me the error, I had to access they key first:

```
getList().then(items => setRpaList(items.rpa));
```

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to have a `useEffect` to make the network call in your component, so that it fetches the data after render, and a `useState` to bind the variable data to. Then once the async call resolves (i.e. in the callback), call the state setter function with the resulting data to refresh the data on the page.

This article provides a good explanation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-call-web-apis-with-the-useeffect-hook-in-react

You can also start a spinner on render, and kill the spinner once the fetching callback runs.

Note that `console.log` does not guarantee that it will log the data as it was at the time the statement was executed, which means that the `jsonResponse` when that line was run may be (in this case, it is) different then what you observed outputted in your console.